# How to filter a data set on a specific date range?

Tags: r, date, subset

If I have a data set and want to sum a specific column on the basis of the specific date range in r?
for example 
Dataset

```
Guest  Sales  date
A        50      2018-08-10
B        180     2018-08-10
C         20     2018-08-15
D         390    2018-08-20
```

And I want the sum of sales between 2018-08-10 and 2018-08-16 ?

Comment: Please keep your data as text not image. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
sum(df[df$date >="2018-08-10" & df$date<="2018-08-16",]$Sales)
```

or

```
sum(subset(df, date>="2018-08-10" & date<="2018-08-16")$Sales)
```

For reproductivity:

```
df <- data.table::fread("Guest  Sales  date
                         A        50      2018-08-10
                         B        180     2018-08-10
                         C         20     2018-08-15
                         D         390    2018-08-20")
```

Comment: But, I need the sum of sales in the duration of 2018-08-10 and 2018-08-16 . which should be 250 not 20

Comment: this is as simple as adding `>=` and `<=` instead of only `>` and `<`. I've edited my answer to suit your needs

Answer (score 0):

A solution with the library `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  filter(date > "2018-08-10" & date < "2018-08-16") %>% 
  summarise(sum_sales = sum(Sales))
#    sum_sales
# 1        20
```

Data:

```
df <- data.table::fread("Guest  Sales  date
                         A        50      2018-08-10
                        B        180     2018-08-10
                        C         20     2018-08-15
                        D         390    2018-08-20", data.table=FALSE)
```